# How to remove vocal from a sound track prefereably mp3

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3, jmf

Did anyone ever tried or worked on an app that removes vocal data from the mp3 file leaving the midi/the background music track.

Is there any open source lib for that to accomplish and how far this is attainable.

Appreciate the ideas if any.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Try Audacity. I believe it has a feature that attempts to do just that. Not sure how effective it is.

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..Yes you are right audacity does that actually ...and the source code is in cpp,but I am not sure how I could do this in java..pls advice

Comment: I'm not aware of an open source java library to do this, I think you'll have to look at the source and convert it.

Answer (score 1):

it's a late answer, but have you ever tried a hardware solution for this.
simply use a capacitor filtering attached to speaker-jack to block human-voice level frequencies. and then re-record the output using mic input.

mehmet